# How to pass the hash (#) through Uri.parse

Tags: android, string, android-studio, android-intent, str-replace

I want to pass a # through Uri.parse. Now I am getting the value in the `number` variable but when I click on the button, the # suddenly disappears, why does this happen?

```
list_But.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v("Value before Clicked", item.toString());
        String number = item.replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", "");

        Log.v("Value after Clicked", number.toString());
        Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: You'll need to `Uri.encode()` the number.

Comment: thanks.i tried to find it but i didn't get the answer.